# Test $b_n = \frac{(n+1)^3 - n^3 - cn^2}{n}$ for convergence and give its limit if it exists.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $c\in\mathbb{C}$.

We have \begin{align*}b_n&=\frac{(n+1)^3 - n^3 - cn^2}{n}\\&=\frac{n(3n+3+cn)}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\\&=(3-c)n+\frac{1}{n}+3\end{align*}
Am I right in arguing that the sequence is divergent, since for $c > 3$ the series converges towards $+\infty$ and for $c < 3$ it converges towards $-\infty$? Or is this missing the point?

Comment: Well, there is also a third case besides $c \gt 3$ and $c \lt 3$. Also note that $c \in \mathbb{C}$ so the inequalities don't make sense.

Comment: In which case the series would converge towards $3$, right? But overall is it divergent because of this argument?

Comment: Given $c$ *complex*, the concept of $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ starts to become muddied, it is better to refer to them both as the same thing: $\infty$.  I wouldn't call the limit when $c=3-i$ "positive infinifty" nor would I call it "negative infinity."  See [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere).

Comment: that being said, @dxiv's comment is slightly misleading.  In terms of *complex* $c$, the symbols $>$ and $<$ don't mean anything useful.  There are two cases.  $c=3$ and $c\neq 3$.

Comment: @woofy I am interested in the sequence.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, would it be alright to express it as $b_n\longrightarrow \pm i\infty$ for $c\neq 3$ then?

Comment: @JMoravitz I had that (sort of) covered in the second part of my comment.

Comment: @math_mu no.  Again, in terms of complex numbers, the very concept of "$+\infty,-\infty,i\infty,-i\infty$" etc... are flawed.  Refer to them all as the same object, $\infty$, specifically an unsigned infinity.  I refer you again to my link to the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) on wikipedia.

Comment: @math_mu You can show that $|b_n|$ is unbounded for $c \ne 3\,$, and use that $|b_n|$ unbounded $\implies b_n$ divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Collecting the comments into a CW answer.*)

> for $c > 3$ the series converges towards $+\infty$ and for $c < 3$ it converges towards $-\infty$

This is wrong since $c \in \mathbb{C}$ is a complex number and cannot be compared with $\gt$ or $\lt$ against $3$.

Hints, instead:

- $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}+3$ is convergent so $b_n$ converges $\displaystyle \iff b_n-\frac{1}{n}-3 = (3-c) n$ converges
- $|(3-c) n| = |3-c| \cdot n$ is unbounded for $c \ne 3$ therefore $(3-c)n$ diverges for $c \ne 3$